# Can events only have one call out at a time?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

Say I have an event like this:

```
SomeClass.SomeEvent += MyMethodToCall();

...

public void MyMethodToCall()
{
     if (CheckToSeeIfFormIsAlreadyShowing())
     {
         SomeForm someForm = new SomeForm();
         someForm.ShowDialog();
     }
     else
     {
         DoSomeStuff();
     }
}
```

If user interaction with `SomeForm` causes the SomeEvent to fire again then will MyMethodToCall be called again while `someForm` is still showing?

My evidence is seems to show that it will not.

My question is why?  The event happened again.  Why wouldn't `MyMethodToCall` get called again (and then end up calling `DoSomeStuff()`?

I am guessing that it is just not possible (still not sure why).  Assuming it is not possible, can I show the dialog on a separate thread (`begininvoke`)?  (I seem to recall that UI all needs to happen on the same thread so I am hesitant to try that).

I need to have the event get called again if it happens again (even if the `SomeForm` dialog is still showing.  Any ideas on how I can do that would be great!

*Note: This is clearly a contrived example, I have tried to condense my complex code into an example that demonstrates the real issue I am working with.  (Meaning please don't attack my example.)*

Comment: If the dialog window is modal, you areprobably blocking the your main thread till it closes.

Comment: +1 yep ShowDialog blocks the thread, you will get the event as soon as you close the form

Comment: I do get it then, but that is too late.  I need it while the form is open.

Comment: Does someForm.Show() work for you? ShowDialog sounds like open a modal window. If that's the case, ShowDialog() won't return until the window is closed. That's probably why the second invocation is being blocked. I am guessing when you close the form, it appears again?

Comment: I thought I'd point out that the `()` in `SomeClass.SomeEvent += MyMethodToCall();` would result in trying to assign a void.  I'm sure this isn't your problem... obviously you'd get a compiler error and fix it easily.

Comment: @Kai Wang - Alas, I need it to be modal still.  The event and its logic are not part of the form class (or any other form class).  The event just opens the form in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments from above, here's what I think happens.

The SomeClass.SomeEvent event is fired from a background thread that belongs to your driver. This background thread is probably designed to wait on some internal handle or queue, and then trigger the event when needed.

What you did, is call ShowDialog on this background thread. This effectively blocks that thread, as it will not be able to continue triggering the event until your handler returns, which will happen only after the dialog is closed.

The solution I would suggest is to avoid showing UI on the driver's background thread, and keep the event handler as short as possible. Basically all you need to do is to call BeginInvoke on your control, in order to call ShowDialog from your UI thread.

So the code would be something like this:

```
SomeClass.SomeEvent += SomeEventHandler;
...
...
...
void SomeEventHandler()
{
    // I'm assuming this code is in a class derived from Form
    this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(HandleEventOnUIThread));
}

void HandlerEventOnUIThread()
{
    if (CheckToSeeIfFormIsAlreadyShowing())
    {
        SomeForm someForm = new SomeForm();
        someForm.ShowDialog();
    }
    else
    {
        DoSomeStuff();
    }
}
```

This way, the handling of SomeClass.SomeEvent will return immediately, and the background thread will be able to trigger the event again when needed.

Comment: This is close to what I ended up doing.  (I had to create a new thread and call invoke from that because my project is a compact framework project and BeginInvoke is not supported on the Compact Framework).  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

It is certainly technically possible.  If SomeEvent is fired by a Timer for example.  Not that you would not notice, the stack of dialog windows is quite visible.

ShowDialog() takes counter-measures to prevent this from happening.  It is *exactly* equivalent to DoEvents(), a method that has gotten a lot of bad rap.  But ShowDialog prevents the vast majority of re-entrancy nastiness by disabling all the windows that are owned by the thread.  The user thus cannot do anything troublesome like again clicking the button that started the dialog, producing two of them.  Or closing the main window, leaving the code still running but without a user interface, the typical lossage for DoEvents().

Without the user being able to intrude and alter the program flow, there isn't much chance that an event fires and you didn't count on it or hadn't seen the behavior while testing.  Don't worry too much about it, you'll notice and you'll hear about it.  And it is easy to fix with a flag.  Although an exception would be a better idea.

Answer (score 3):

Your event can be called twice.

The reason is, that the call to ShowDialog doesn't really *block* the thread. ShowDialog runs an internal loop that pumps messages from the message queue, in order to return only after the dialog is closed.

What this means, is that while ShowDialog hasn't yet returned, UI events are still being fired and handled on your UI thread.

So, if for example you are triggering your SomeClass.SomeEvent event from the event handler for some UI event (e.g. a button click on the dialog), then the event handler for SomeClass.SomeEvent *will* be invoked.

If you break the debugger and look at the stack trace, you will see your original event handler, calling ShowDialog, calling a message pump, calling some UI event handler, invoking your SomeClass.SomeEvent handler a second time.

If your problem is that the event doesn't get called a second time, can you please provide more details on how you are triggering your event? Did you try to put a break point on the line that invokes your event to ensure that it actually got executed?

I hope this answers your question.

Ran

Comment: The event is not a UI event.  It is a hardware based event (a scanner to be precise).  And I put a break point in and the second time I scan the event does not get called. (But it does the first time.)

Comment: In that case, another direction I would guess: is it possible that you are triggering the event on a different instance of SomeClass, one on which you haven't registered to the event yet?

Comment: Can you please show how you are invoking your event? Are you by anychance using something like Control.Invoke...?

Comment: I don't invoke the event.  The driver for the scanner invokes the event.  I just consume it.

Comment: I think I understand. The driver's thread probably reads some internal queue and then invokes the event. In your case, after the first event invocation, this thread is now inside a message loop waiting for the dialog to close. Now even though the driver detects a new scan, the event won't be invoked because this thread first has to return from the first invocation in order to continue processing the queue. I would suggest you don't show GUI on the driver's background thread. Instead, use Control.Invoke to defer execution from the background thread to your UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
someForm.Show();
```

instead of ShowDialog(), and the event will continue to fire :)

Comment: Alas, I need the dialog that is shown to be modal.  I just want the logic to keep working under the hood.  (It may be relevant to note that `SomeForm` does not own this event nor is the handler in it's class (or any other form class for that matter).

Comment: Hmm, another way is to set IsMDIContainer to the parent form and still call the Show() instead of ShowDialog. So the new form will be on top of it's parent. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.ismdicontainer.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Fire SomeEvent in a background thread. In the handler when you want to show the dialog you must marshal the call to the UI thread. DoSomeStuff will be executed on the worker thread even when the dialog is still open.